# Read/Load multiple XML in a single test initialize with NDbUnit

Tags: unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework, ndbunit

I am trying to use the NDbUnit. I have created seperate XSD for each table instead of one large XSD for complete database.

My tests run fine when I use only single XSD and singe xml read. However for a perticular test, I need to have data in two or three different (but related) tables. If I try to read more than one xsd and xml, then it throws exception.

Here is my code

```
        [ClassInitialize()]
        public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
        {
            IDbConnection connection = DbConnection.GetCurrentDbConnection();
            _mySqlDatabase = new NDbUnit.Core.SqlClient.SqlDbUnitTest(connection);
            _mySqlDatabase.ReadXmlSchema(@"Data\CompanyMaster.xsd");  
            _mySqlDatabase.ReadXml(@"Data\CompanyMaster.xml");
            _mySqlDatabase.ReadXmlSchema(@"Data\License.xsd");
            _mySqlDatabase.ReadXml(@"Data\License.xml");
            _mySqlDatabase.ReadXmlSchema(@"Data\LicenseDetails.xsd");
            _mySqlDatabase.ReadXml(@"Data\LicenseDetails.xml");
            _mySqlDatabase.ReadXmlSchema(@"RelatedLicense.xsd");
            _mySqlDatabase.ReadXml(@"Data\RelatedLicense.xml");    
        }
```

Here is the exception I get at the point where i try to read License.XSD as shown above

> Class Initialization method
>   ESMS.UnitTest.CompanyManagerTest.MyClassInitialize
>   threw exception.
>   System.ArgumentException:
>   System.ArgumentException: Item has
>   already been added. Key in dictionary:
>   'EnableTableAdapterManager'  Key being
>   added: 'EnableTableAdapterManager'.

I am not sure if this is the correct way of reading multiple XML,XSD with NDbUnit. I googled and ***Overflowed*** (i.e. searched stack overflow), but could not get any sensible direction. Could someone explain what is going wrong and how to correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sbohlen showed me the way.

It's true that as thing stands as of now, loading of multiple XSD's is not supported.

However fortunately loading of multiple XMLs against single XSD is possible.

So what I did was created a single XSD and pulled in all related tables onto it. Then used the `AppendXml` sytanx available along side of ReadXml. This way I could load the required test data into multiple tables and my tests started getting passed.

This link would share more lights about the `AppendXml` http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/issues/detail?id=27

Comment: Awesome! I'd just like to note that there is an alternative - namely, creating a new `INDbUnit` each time you need to read a new XSD.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't how NDbUnit is intended to be used.  There is no support for reading multiple XSD or XML files into a single test-scope.  NDbUnit uses the information in the single XSD to analyze relationships (FKs, etc.) between your tables in order to be able to properly manipulate the tables during its CRUD operations and so the requirement is that the single XSD describe the entire scope of the tables that you want NDbUnit to manipulate during a test-run.

It *might* be possible to load multiple XML files (containing your test data) but this is not a tested/supported scenario.  I'd be interested in understanding what usage scenario you have that would preclude having just one XML file with your needed test data.

But its *definitely* the case that only a single XSD file (containing the schema of one or more tables and their relationships, etc.) can be loaded at a time.

Hope this clears this up a bit.